# Не объявляется переменная в JS

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

Есть некоторый, мною написанный код на JS.

```
onload = function(){
/* events */
O('start').onclick = function(){start()}
O('backtooptions').onclick = function(){stop()}
O('skip').onclick = function(){skip()}
O('confirmanswer').onclick = function(){confirmanswer()}

/*variables*/
settin = new Object();
settin = {
    time:0,
    negative: false,
    sym:{
        add:false,
        sub:false,
        mul:false,
        div:false
    },
    range:{
        min: 0,
        max:0
    }
}

function stop(){
    S('play').display='none';
    S('options').display='';
}
function confirmanswer(){

}
function checktime(time){
    if(time <= 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(time > 10){
        return 10;
    }
    else{
        return time;
    }
}
function checksettings(){
    var signs = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < signs.length(); i++){
    }

}

function start(){

    S('options').display='none';
    S('play').display='';
    options.time = checktime(Math.floor(parseInt(O('time').value)));


}
train = "Hello";
function generator(min,max){
}
}
```

У меня есть несколько вопросов по нему, а именно:

**Вопрос первый:**
    После объявления переменной например `var a = 'a';`, при попытке вызвать ее в браузерной консоли, пишет что: "переменная не определена", но если код взаимодействует с ней, то все работает(но ее также нельзя вызвать из консоли).

Проблема решена с помощью удаления `var`.

Собственно вопрос: Почему переменная объявляется только при отсутствии `var`?

**Вопрос два:** 
    С функциями тоже самое, их нельзя вызвать через консоль, но вот например, на события функции вешаются отлично.

**PS**

Что касается функций O и S:

```
function O(i){
    return typeof i == 'object' ? i : document.getElementById(i);
}
function S(i){
    return O(i).style;
}
```

Comment: где в вашем коде переменная `a` и функции `o` и `s`?

Comment: @DreamChild ,  
"Проблема в том что вы используете синие маркеры, а надо красные"(с) Видео про 7 красных линий.  |   Прочитайте пожалуйста полностью вопрос, я указал что за функция O и S.

Comment: А про [замыкания](https://learn.javascript.ru/functions-closures) вы слыхали? Стоит почитать, может вопрос отпадёт.

Comment: @vladimirch в первом приведённом куске кода этих функций, как и переменной нет. Вы же для чего-то привели этот кусок, не так ли? В данном случае не имеет значения, как выглядят эти ваши функции, важно то, как и откуда вы их вызываете. Но это у вас не показано

Comment: @DreamChild , Переменная 'a' была приведена к примеру. Если для вас это действительно важно, возьмите пожалуйста любую другую.

Comment: @DreamChild вопрос не о функциях O и S, они как раз таки работают отлично.

Comment: @vladimirch для меня важно то, как вы их используете в вашем коде. Само по себе объявление вида `var a = 'a';` работает нормально в любом браузере, очевидно, что проблема кроется конкретно в вашем коде, в том, как вы эту переменную используете и где. И я даже на 99% уверен, что знаю, в чём именно ваша проблема, но для того, чтобы не быть голословным, нужно понимать, как именно работает с этими переменными ваш код. Но вы почему-то упорно это скрываете

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда переменная объявлена в функции, то доступа к ней из вне нет, это локальная переменная.

```js
(function() {
  var f = "первая";
  console.log(f);
  d = "вторая";
  console.log(d)
})()

console.log(d)
```

А если ты  переменную не объявляешь. Парсер делает следующее. создает вне функции переменную var d; потом в функции в присваивает значение и уже она становится не локальной, а глобальной. По этому без var она тебе доступна вне функции

Comment: Это действительно работает, спасибо большое.

Comment: всегда пожалуйста...